# Mimic Frame behavior in HTML5

Tags: html, jquery

I want to build a site with three frames layout (header, content and footer), with the header and footer frames containing elements that DO NOT RELOAD, only the  content frame reloads as needed. I want to build this using HTML5. What should be the approach to build this. Is there any other solution than using Ajax here ?

Comment: Ajax would be the only solution, aside from iframes or simply changing the content with javascript

Comment: One solution would be to have all your pages contents inside one file, inside a DIV, hidden, and call (show) them depending on the clicked link.